# python sphinx cannot find module

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to start using sphinx to document python but I keep getting errors that my module cannot be found.
My directory structure is as such

-src

--test.py

--Docs

---All sphinx files...

I have this in conf.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

autodoc is turned on

the following in index.rst

```
.. automodule:: public_fn_with_sphinxy_docstring
```

test.py contains the following line

```
def public_fn_with_sphinxy_docstring(name, state=None):
"""This function does something.

:param name: The name to use.
:type name: str.
:param state: Current state to be in.
:type state: bool.
:returns:  int -- the return code.
:raises: AttributeError, KeyError

"""
return 0
```

I am getting this error from sphinx

> ImportError: No module named 'public_fn_with_sphinxy_docstring'

I am at a loss what I am missing. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks,
Amish

Here is conf.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# test documentation build configuration file, created by
# sphinx-quickstart on Thu Dec 29 15:04:40 2016.
#
# This file is execfile()d with the current directory set to its
# containing dir.
#
# Note that not all possible configuration values are present in this
# autogenerated file.
#
# All configuration values have a default; values that are commented out
# serve to show the default.

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
import os
import sys
#sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

# -- General configuration ------------------------------------------------

# If your documentation needs a minimal Sphinx version, state it here.
#
# needs_sphinx = '1.0'

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# The suffix(es) of source filenames.
# You can specify multiple suffix as a list of string:
#
# source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
source_suffix = '.rst'

# The master toctree document.
master_doc = 'index'

# General information about the project.
project = 'test'
copyright = '2016, bhameenee seegolam'
author = 'bhameenee seegolam'

# The version info for the project you're documenting, acts as replacement for
# |version| and |release|, also used in various other places throughout the
# built documents.
#
# The short X.Y version.
version = '1'
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags.
release = '1'

# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
#
# This is also used if you do content translation via gettext catalogs.
# Usually you set "language" from the command line for these cases.
language = None

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This patterns also effect to html_static_path and html_extra_path
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

# The name of the Pygments (syntax highlighting) style to use.
pygments_style = 'sphinx'

# If true, `todo` and `todoList` produce output, else they produce nothing.
todo_include_todos = False


# -- Options for HTML output ----------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'alabaster'

# Theme options are theme-specific and customize the look and feel of a theme
# further.  For a list of options available for each theme, see the
# documentation.
#
# html_theme_options = {}

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']


# -- Options for HTMLHelp output ------------------------------------------

# Output file base name for HTML help builder.
htmlhelp_basename = 'testdoc'


# -- Options for LaTeX output ---------------------------------------------

latex_elements = {
    # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
    #
    # 'papersize': 'letterpaper',

    # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
    #
    # 'pointsize': '10pt',

    # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
    #
    # 'preamble': '',

    # Latex figure (float) alignment
    #
    # 'figure_align': 'htbp',
}

# Grouping the document tree into LaTeX files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title,
#  author, documentclass [howto, manual, or own class]).
latex_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'test.tex', 'test Documentation',
     'bhameenee seegolam', 'manual'),
]


# -- Options for manual page output ---------------------------------------

# One entry per manual page. List of tuples
# (source start file, name, description, authors, manual section).
man_pages = [
    (master_doc, 'test', 'test Documentation',
     [author], 1)
]


# -- Options for Texinfo output -------------------------------------------

# Grouping the document tree into Texinfo files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title, author,
#  dir menu entry, description, category)
texinfo_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'test', 'test Documentation',
     author, 'test', 'One line description of project.',
     'Miscellaneous'),
]
```

Here is index.rst

```
.. test documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Thu Dec 29 15:04:40 2016.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to test's documentation!
================================


.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

.. automodule:: public_fn_with_sphinxy_docstring


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public_fn_with_sphinxy_docstring` is a *function* in the `test` module (the file is called test.py).

So the following does not work:

```
.. automodule:: public_fn_with_sphinxy_docstring
```

You need to change it to this:

```
.. automodule:: test
   :members:
```

Note the `:members:` option. Without it, only a module-level docstring would be included in the output.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help. It seems to create the doc now but sphinx is still throwing out this error  `reading sources... [100%] index
C:\perforce\D3C2CommsLibrary\MainLine\sphinx\Docs\index.rst:7: SEVERE: Duplicate
 ID: "module-test".
looking for now-outdated files... none found`
  
Not sure why

Comment: If my answer solved the problem in the question, then please accept it. If you need help with the "Duplicate ID" warning, please post a new question for that.